# Interpreting zero-inflated Poisson regression

Tags: r, poisson-regression, zero-inflation

I fitted a zero-inflated Poisson regression with "group" (4 groups in total) as indepentdent variable and nchoice (frequency that a person choose a certain answer) as dependent variable. I got this output:

```
Call:
zeroinfl(formula = nchoice ~ group | group, data = data)

Pearson residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.4080 -0.3979 -0.3717 -0.3198  3.3936 

Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.65243    0.18209   3.583  0.00034 ***
group2       0.03735    0.28597   0.131  0.89609    
group3      -0.18642    0.28758  -0.648  0.51684    
group4      -0.38739    0.30063  -1.289  0.19754    

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.2833     0.2689   4.772 1.83e-06 ***
group2        0.5373     0.4125   1.303    0.193    
group3        0.1184     0.4025   0.294    0.769    
group4       -0.1389     0.4138  -0.336    0.737    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 14 
Log-likelihood: -276.9 on 8 Df
```

My questions are: Should I understand

- the count model (1st part of the model) as a Poisson regression when all cases with nchoice = 0 are excluded? -> The exp(Intercept) should show me the average value of nchoice in group 1 when all the cases with nchoice = 0 are "deleted". But it is not the case.
- the zero-inflation model (2nd part of the model) as a logistic regression when all cases with nchoice > 0 are recoded into 1 (nchoice as binary variable) -> The exp(Intercept) should show me the odds of having nchoice = 0 in group 1. But it is also not the case.

I would be very thankful if you could show me how I can interpret the output.